# order view by contextual filter

Tags: commerce, views

I've a site developed with [Drupal commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce).

I'm using the context filter to display a block with related products.
I want to display 4 products, first ones I've selected with entity field, if there aren't (or not enough) ones that have the same category, even if these are not enough I want ones that have the category with the same parent of my product.

To do this I used a view and set the contextual filters with **Views Module Contextual Filters OR**. With my contextual filter I'm able to extract the related products, then the products of the same category, but can't extract products that have the same parent category. Also I can't order my products, first related ones, then the ones with the same categories, etc.

I am attaching a screenshot for clarity.

[image]

Any suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: You need Taxonomy Term with Depth as a contextual filter instead of Has Taxonomy Term ID, it should be available considering your relationships.

Comment: It's ok. Now I need to order my products... first related ones, then the ones with the same categories, etc. There is any module to do this?